# PowerShell clearing memory after finishing

Tags: powershell, memory, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a [PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198906/find-strings-in-one-file-in-another-and-output-certain-columns) that reads a large CSV file (4GB+), finds certain lines, then writes the lines to other files.

I'm noticing that when it gets to "echo "Processed $datacounter total lines in the $datafile file"" the last line of the script, it doesn't actually finish until 5-10 minutes later.

What is it doing for that period? When it does finish, memory usage drops off significantly. Is there a way to force it to clear memory at the end of the script?

[Screenshot of Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrFyN.png)

[Screenshot of script timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr78k.png)

Here is the final version of my script for reference.

```
    # Get the filename
    $datafile = Read-Host "Filename"
    $dayofweek = Read-Host "Day of week (IE 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday..)"
    $campaignWriters = @{}


    # Create campaign ID hash table
    $campaignByID = @{}
    foreach($c in (Import-Csv 'campaigns.txt' -Delimiter '|')) {
        foreach($id in ($c.CampaignID -split ' ')) {
            $campaignByID[$id] = $c.CampaignName
        }

        foreach($cname in ($c.CampaignName)) {
            $writer = $campaignWriters[$cname] = New-Object IO.StreamWriter($dayofweek + $cname + '_filtered.txt')
            if($dayofweek -eq 1) {
                $writer.WriteLine("ID1|ID2|ID3|ID4|ID5|ID6|Time|Time-UTC-Sec")
            }
        }
    }

    # Display the campaigns
    $campaignByID.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value 

    # Read in data file
    $encoding = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-1')
    $datareader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($datafile, $encoding)
    $datacounter = 0

    echo "Starting.."
    get-date -Format g

    while (!$datareader.EndOfStream) {
        $data = $datareader.ReadLine().Split('þ')

        # Find the Campaign in the hashtable
        $campaignName = $campaignByID[$data[3]] 
        if($campaignName) {
            $writer = $campaignWriters[$campaignName]
            # If a campaign name was returned from the hash, add the line using that campaign's writer
            $writer.WriteLine(($data[20,3,5,8,12,14,0,19] -join '|'))
        }
        $datacounter++;
    }

    $datareader.Close()
    foreach ($writer in $campaignWriters.Values) {
        $writer.Close()
    }

    echo "Done!"
    get-date -Format g
    echo "Processed $datacounter total lines in the $datafile file"
```

Comment: the script is not actually done until the last line is complete.  use 
"done: $(get-date -Format g)" to see when it happens exactly

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `campaigns.txt` is the mult-gigabyte file you are referring to. If it's the other file(s), this might not make as much sense.

If so, invoking `import-csv` the inside parenthesis then using the `foreach` statement to iterate through them is what's driving your memory usage so high.   A better alternative would be use a PowerShell pipeline to stream records from the file without needing to keep all of them in memory at the same time.   You achieve this by changing the `foreach` statment into a `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
  Import-Csv 'campaigns.txt' -Delimiter '|' | ForEach-Object {
        foreach($id in ($_.CampaignID -split ' ')) {
            $campaignByID[$id] = $_.CampaignName
        }
   }
```

The .NET garbage collector is optimized cases where the majority of objects are short-lived.   Therefor this change should result in a noticeable performance increase, as well as reduced wind-down time at the end.

I advise *against* forcing garbage collection with `[System.GC]::Collect()`, the garbage collector knows best when it should run.   The reasons for this are complex, if you really want to know details why this is true, [Maoni's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maoni/) has a wealth of details about garbage collection in the .NET environment.

Comment: Thanks for the info about garbage collection. The multi-GB file is actually the `$datafile` that's being read by the StreamReader. The `campaigns.txt` file is very small, only like 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not work, but you can try to tell garbage collection to run:

```
[System.GC]::Collect()
```

You don't have fine grained control over it though, and it may help to `Remove-Variable` or set variables to `$null` for some things before running it so that there aren't references to the data anymore.